# A quick question on product of Smith normal form

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices

I am having trouble get a hold on this problem for a couple of days: if I have two $n$ by $n$ matrices $A,B$ with entries in some principle ideal domain $D$, and suppose their Smith normal form is diagonal matrices diag$\{a_i\}$ and diag$\{b_i\}$, now suppose the determinant of $AB$ is nonzero, and the Smith normal form for $AB$ is diag$\{c_i\}$, then why is it true that $a_i,b_i$ divides $c_i$?

I know the Smith normal form give us a nice way to relate the generators of a module and basis for the corresponding finitely generated free module, but I am having trouble understand the picture when there are two matrices involved.